# injecting provider in java main

Tags: java, guice

I have a custom provider using Guice with some pseudo code below:

```
public class MyProvider implements Provider<String> {
    public String get() {
        System.out.println("Called MyProvider.get()");
        return "abcd";
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(String.class).toProvider(MyProvider.class);
    }
}

public class MyManager {
    private MyProvider<String> myProvider;

    @Inject
    public MyManager(Provider<String> myProvider) { this.myProvider = myProvider; }
}
```

There's a MyManager object representing what we are going to build out in the future after Guice gets wired up.  Now in order to actually start this, I'm a bit lost...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());

    // not sure what to do here.  This doesn't work but I thought it'd be something like this
    MyManager mgr = new MyManager(injector.getProvider(MyProvider.class));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the "preferred way," but this seems to work:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
MyManager mgr = injector.getInstance(MyManager.class);
```

Thoughts if this is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc for [Injector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git-history/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getProvider(java.lang.Class<T>)):

> Returns the provider used to obtain instances for the given type.

It sounds like you need to pass the class of the object that the returned provider will supply. Since you need the provider that will return a String I think you need to pass `String.class`.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    MyManager mgr = new MyManager(injector.getProvider(String.class));
}
```

Comment: I do not like this solution, because now you are using "new" to create an instance of MyManager, although it is configured to use dependency injection. Mixing "new" and injection is the root of many hard to debug errors. And when it comes to guice: when you use "new", you can not benefit of any aop features (injectors, ...) anymore.